# Using Secondary Template and URL Structure for Single Custom Post Type Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, timber

I have a WordPress website with a custom post type 'team-bio' with the single pages showing the bio of the respective person.

```
website.com/team-bio/person-name
```

I would like to show a different custom post type single page template so that each person has a page that would show alternate information about this person when the user visits an alternate url

```
website.com/dbc/person-name
```

I've tried the following code but the /dbc/ pages go to a 404 page.

```
// Add custom rewrite rules for the custom post type
function custom_post_type_rewrite_rules() {
    // Define the custom post type name
    $post_type = 'team-bio';
    // Define the custom URL structure for the first template
    $structure1 = '/team-bio/%postname%/';
    // Define the custom URL structure for the second template
    $structure2 = '/dbc/%postname%/';
    // Add the first rewrite rule
    add_rewrite_rule($structure1, 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type . '&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
    // Add the second rewrite rule
    add_rewrite_rule($structure2, 'index.php/dbc/?post_type=' . $post_type . '&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_post_type_rewrite_rules');

// Add custom templates for the custom post type
function custom_post_type_templates($template) {
    // Define the custom post type name
    $post_type = 'team-bio';
    // Get the post
    $post = get_query_var('post_type');
    // Check if it's the custom post type and the URL structure matches the first template
    if ($post == $post_type && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/team-bio/') !== false) {
        // Load the custom template for the first URL structure
        return get_template_directory() . '/templates/single-team-bio.twig';
    }
    // Check if it's the custom post type and the URL structure matches the second template
    if ($post == $post_type && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/dbc/') !== false) {
        // Load the custom template for the second URL structure
        return get_template_directory() . '/templates/dbc.twig';
    }
    // Return the default template
    return $template;
}
add_filter('single_template', 'custom_post_type_templates');
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this work with the following code:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
add_rewrite_rule('^dbc/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=team-bio&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rule' );

// Add custom templates for the custom post type
function custom_post_type_templates($template) {
// Define the custom post type name
$post_type = 'team-bio';
// Get the post
$post = get_query_var('post_type');
// Check if it's the custom post type and the URL structure matches the first template
if ($post == $post_type && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/team-bio/') !== false) {
    // Load the custom template for the first URL structure
    return get_template_directory() . '/templates/single-team-bio.twig';
}
// Check if it's the custom post type and the URL structure matches the second template
if ($post == $post_type && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/dbc/') !== false) {
    // Load the custom template for the second URL structure
    return get_template_directory() . '/templates/dbc.twig';
}
// Return the default template
return $template;
}
add_filter('single_template', 'custom_post_type_templates');
```